# How to create Seach box for database mysql with 2 keyword?

Tags: php

i have been edited some login PHP,
i change username = userName and password = userProffesion

than i create like search with 2 keyword, 
but why after login user, display all image on database?
i want to display picture by userName.

this my code and i dont know whats wrong.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>my database</title>
    <style>
    .form {
        margin: 10% 0 0 10%;
        float: left;
        width: 90%;
    }
    .input {
        padding: 1%;
        color: #777777;
        font-size: 14pt;
        float: left;
        width: 80%; 
        margin-bottom: 1%;
    }
    .submit {
        padding: 1%;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #11b022;
        font-size: 14pt;
        font-family: Times New Roman;
        float: left;
        width: 25%; 
    }
    .welcome {
        color: #11bb22;
        font-size: 13pt;
        font-weight: 900;
        font-family: Centaur;
    }


    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="form">
<span class="welcome">put ID</span>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Contoh : LP/123/VII/2017">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="userProfession" placeholder="put Name">
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Cari">
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userName'])) {
    header("Location: index.php?access_denied");
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Data SP2HP</title>
    <style>
    .welcome {
        color: #11bb22;
        font-size: 25pt;
        font-weight: 900;
        font-family: Centaur;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<center><h1 class="welcome">welcome 

<?php 
echo $_SESSION['userProfession'];
?></h1> </center>
<p> <center>This your pict </center>

<?php 
include_once("connect.php");

$query = "SELECT userPic FROM tbl_users ORDER BY username DESC";
$query = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$query);

if($result = mysqli_query($connect,$query)){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){

    echo   


    '<div><center><a href="'. $row->userPic . '" ><img src ="'. $row->userPic . '" width= "20%"></a></center></div>';

}

mysqli_free_result($result);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</p>
<center><p>klik picture to view in large size</p></center>

<strong><a href="logout.php" type="submit">logout</a><br/>




</body>
</html>
```

connect.php

```
<?php

$host  = 'localhost';
$user  = 'myuser';
$pass = 'mypass';
$db    = 'mydb';

$connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if($connect->connect_error){
    echo 'somethisng wrong';
}

?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$userName = $_POST['userName'];
$userProfession = $_POST['userProfession'];


$query    = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userPic = '$userPic' OR userName = '$userName' AND userProfession = '$userProfession'";
$runquery = $connect->query($query);

if($runquery->num_rows > 0)


{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;
    $_SESSION['userProfession'] =$userProfession; 
    $_SESSION['userPic'] = $userPic;
    header("Location: home.php");

} else {
    echo '<h1>ID or Name wrong </h1>';
}

?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy()){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
```

and this my database

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.2.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Inang: localhost
-- Waktu pembuatan: 04 Feb 2017 pada 16.50
-- Versi Server: 10.0.28-MariaDB
-- Versi PHP: 5.2.17

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Basis data: `mydb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struktur dari tabel `tbl_users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_users` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `userProfession` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `userPic` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=61 ;

--
-- Dumping data untuk tabel `tbl_users`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_users` (`userID`, `userName`, `userProfession`, `userPic`) VALUES
(53, 'LP/119/XI/2016', 'BERTINA', '984264.jpg'),
(54, 'LP/265/V/2016', 'HENDRIAN', '919115.jpg'),
(55, 'LP/09/I/2017', 'ADNAN', '215866.jpg'),
(56, 'LP/04/I/2017', 'ROMMY', '4372.jpg'),
(57, 'LP/122/IX/2016', 'SUKARDI', '808892.jpg'),
(58, 'LP/01/I/2017', 'SYAFRIDA', '169928.jpg'),
(59, 'LP/05/I/2017', 'UNTUNG', '857392.jpg'),
(60, 'B/08/I/2017', 'ZULMIN', '519638.jpg');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Be more specifically. We don't know how is your database look like. What did you try?

Comment: We can't help if we dont know what you've tried. Please add your current code.

Comment: Are you asking us to code it for you? This is _not_ a free coding service. Try first, if you have an issue, come back and show us the _specific_ issue you're having, and we might be able to help you.

Comment: sorry i have create before like that i have been editing